# dotnet run command not listening on https

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-code, https

I am running a simple ASP.Net program on Windows and when I try to run the 'dotnet run' command, I can see it's listening only on http but not on https. I have also executed 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' command to trust the development certificate, but still it's not listening on https. Could you please let me know if I am missing any other settings ?

```
PS C:\Users\test\Documents\TodoApi> dotnet  run 
Building...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5027
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\test\Documents\TodoApi
```

**lanuchsettings.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:40409",
      "sslPort": 44321
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5027",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7130",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HostingAbstractionsWebHostBuilderExtensions.UseUrls` method in your startup class.
If you want to pass the urls in command line then use

```
dotnet run --urls "https://localhost:5027"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start your app by using following CLI command:

```
dotnet run --launch-profile https
```

when you have `https` properties defined in your launchSettings.json file